# Follow user relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I am implementing a follow feature for my users. For this, I followed instruction of micheal hartl tutorial <sub>link needed</sub>, yet I am getting this error:

```
undefined method id' for nil:NilClass  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
```

this is my user model

```
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower


  def following?(user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id)
  end

  def follow!(user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id).destroy
  end
```

this is my relationship model

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

and this is my view

```
<% if current_user.id && current_user.id != user.id %>
  <div id="follow_form">
     <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
        <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
                                                html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
          <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class:"unfollow-button"  %>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
            <%= f.submit "Follow", class:"follow-button"  %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

this is the user controller

```
def show
    @user= User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    if @user
      @posts= Post.all
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = (current_user.blank? ? User.all : User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]))
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code? It might have the root source of the problem.

Comment: How can you tag both rails 3 and rails 4? Which rails version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This means `@user` is nil. Make sure that `@user` object is not null by doing

`= debug @user`

That should print all the details about `@user` object.

Comment: where I do that I am a newbie

Comment: In your view, just do `<%= debug @user %>`

Comment: I didn't say it solves your problem. If it is Nil then you have to figure out why. But it does give you some debug information to see what the value of user is